# Reverse onClick Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a genuine javascript novice and looking some pointers in my learning - not homework nor is it anything commercial.

I have a function here which shows an element which is hidden due to the first 2 lines of the function. I start by clicking the heading and the 2 hidden divs appear, which is exactly what I wanted to happen. However, now when I use this second function, it won't return to it's windown onload state. Why is this? Is there a better way to achieve this?

1st Function

```
  $(window).ready(function(){
         $('.miniC').css("display", "none");
      $('.miniI').css("display", "none");
    $(".heading").click(function(){
      $('.miniC').slideDown();
      $('.miniI').slideDown();

      $('.miniC').show();
      $('.miniI').show();

    });
  });
```

2nd Function (Reverse)

```
  $(window).ready(function(){
    $(".hideOut").click(function(){
      $('.miniC').slideUp();
      $('.miniI').slideUp();

      $('.miniC').hide();
      $('.miniI').hide();

    });
  });
```

Thanks in advance and any reference to good reading material is appreciated.

*** Corrected Missing closing quote - this was a mistake of me typing it into Stack Overflow - Sorry! ***

Comment: `$('.miniC).show();` you're missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to toggle the visibility of an element, and since you're already sliding it, why not just use `slideToggle`:

```
$(".miniC").css("display", "none");
$(".miniI").css("display", "none");
$(".heading").click(function () {
    $(".miniC").slideToggle();
    $(".miniI").slideToggle();
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/6M7Zh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Because `slideUp()` and `hide()` are written inside the *click event*. So, it wont fire on *window ready*, but only `onclick` of `$(".hideOut")`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to call `.hide()` and `.show()` - they will be dealt with as part of the slide functions. However, you're calling them immediately after the slide, but that takes a while to complete (400ms by default) meaning that `.hide()` fires before `.slideUp()` completes.

Answer (score 0):

Outside the question scope, but still applicable.

```
 $('.miniC').css("display", "none");
 $('.miniI').css("display", "none");
```

This part of the page functionality should probably in CSS, which will result in the browser rendering the initial paint of the page correctly.  In your case the browser paints the "miniC" and "miniI" elements, then your jQuery code updates the CSS display property to "none" for both individually.  Triggering two additional repaints of the page.  So, basically with the jQuery code you are drawing the page three times for an effect that could achieved with a single paint.

Then like Charlie said add a listener for the click.

```
$(".heading").click(function () {
    $(".miniC").slideToggle();
    $(".miniI").slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a typo in your first function.
a single quote is missing in the line:

```
$('.miniC).show();
```

Comment: This wasn't the problem. It was my typing mistake when asking the question - apologises